# Insert web frame with WebRTC support in own application

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit, webrtc

We are about to extend an existing application based on Qt 5 to support video/audio-chat using WebRTC.

We already tried to use the Qt 5.0.2 built-in QtWebkit widget without success as getUserMedia() seems to be invisible for JavaScript or is not implemented in general. After further research we found that WebRTC is currently not supported by the latest version of QtWebkit. For example the necessary libraries like libjingle are not included.

In support of this we found the following on the internet:

- http://qt-project.org/search/tag/webrtc (team working on the integration of WebRTC into QtWebkit)
- https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-qt/2013-February/003501.html (several unsuccessful attempts to use WebRTC with QtWebkit)

Has anyone figured out how to integrate video/audio-chat using WebRTC into your own application?

Comment: did you ever find a good solution - did you test node-webkit etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is currently switching from webkit to chromium. As far as I know this new engine will support webrtc from the start. This new project is called [QtWebEngine](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebEngine). You can get the current state from [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/qtwebengine/source/master%3a). I already compiled it and it pulls in libjingle and wraps it. Perhaps you should grab the source of QtWebEngine and test with this.